# Let (X,d) is metric space. Is it correct diam(A)=diam(co(A))

Tags: real-analysis

Let (X,d)be a  metric vector space. The diameter of a set A⊂X is defined to be
diam(A)= sup{d(x,y):x,y∈A}. Is it correct that diam(co(A))=diam(A)?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: What is $\operatorname{co}(A)$? Is this supposed to be the convex hull? In general metric spaces don't have a notion of convexity since you don't have an addition on them.

Comment: If $co(A)$ denotes the closure of $A$, then yes: this is true. If it denotes the complement of $A$, then no.

Comment: It depends on the metric. If it is well-adapted to the vector space structure, then yes, if not (I still assume it induces a vector space topology), then the convex hull can have strictly greater diameter.

Comment: If X is a normed space, we have: diam(co(A))=diam(A).  But if let X is a metric vector space, i cann't proved that.